# QML module not found error

Tags: qt-creator, qml

When using QtCreator, I display a qml file in the editor. The qml file is for a file named `main.qml` that is a plugin.

I then click on the `Design` button. It displays the error message: `QML module not found`.

If I take the `Go to error` link it goes to a line containing the following `import com.name.os.app.all 1.0`. This is the location of various component qml files needed by the plugin.

I have added the path `c:\users\me\ui\viewer\` to my `QML_IMPORT_PATH` `env` variable. If QtCreater appends the `com.name...` from the qml file import statement to the pathname I added to `QML_IMPORT_PATH`, it would find the desired directory. It doesn't.

The project uses qmake.

I have tried using `qmlplugindump.exe` to generate a `qmltypes` file for my main qml view container file, but `qmlplugindump.exe` gives me an error saying the `component is not ready` and `file::///c:/Users/name/ui/viewer/modules/app/qml/com/name/os/app/all/typelist.qml:2:1 module MyViewContainer.qml is not installed`.

The command I used was `qmlplugindump.exe MyViewContainer.qml 1.0 c:\users\myname\ui\viewer\modules\app\qml\com\name\os\app\all\ > ...`

Answer (score 7):

**This Error Ruined My Life**
**Real Solution** for "QML module not found error":
lets say if you have plugins in directory like this, with qmldir inside it 
 `"myproject/modules/mymodule/blabla.qmldir"`
you need to import parent directory like this in ".pro" file  :

```
QML_IMPORT_PATH += $$PWD/modules
```

not like this (this one wont work):
<s>`QML_IMPORT_PATH += $$PWD/modules/mymodule`</s>
//---------------------------------------------
side note:
this is going to happen in other part of qml too like **qmlplugindump** you need to give parent directory not exact folder!
but **windeployqt** is working with exact folder

for example:

```
qmlplugindump lib 1.0 C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\projectName\3rdparty > C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\projectName\3rdparty\lib\lib.qmltypes
```

//---------------------------------------------
and second most important part is **QML emulation layer**
in Qt Creator go to **tools->option->Qt Quick->Qt Quick Designer**
select "**Use Qml emulation layer that is built with the selected qt**"
if its already selected look at textbox under that "Top level build path"
it should refer to Qt version bin directory which should be same as plugins Qt version :

```
..\5.12.1\msvc2017\bin
```

for me its :(it should be same version as you used for kits and blabla)

```
C:\QtN\5.12.1\msvc2017\bin
```

it should not be like this one :

```
C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\QtProject\qtcreator\qmlpuppet
```

dont forget to deploy after adding new item in plugins(cmd command) :

```
windeployqt --qmldir C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\projectName C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\build-projectName-5_12-Debug\debug
```

and plugin dump :

```
qmlplugindump lib 1.0 C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\projectName\3rdparty > C:\Users\Administrator\Documents\projectName\3rdparty\lib\lib.qmltypes
```

after this point if QtCreator gives error for new Objects in Plugins you need to restart QtCreator thats it!

if still there is problems you need to - Clean All - Run Qmake - Rebuild all which solves so many issues.
and in some cases you need to put your qml files into `5.13.1\msvc2017\qml` or whatever is for your qt version

Answer (score 1):

Have you tested this plugin fully? I ask this because I have written a number of plugins and have run into this issue multiple times.
Possible issues include the version of Qt you are using, and some form of naming error in the plugin uri / classname.

I have an app that I build for multiple versions of Qt and it seems that the qmlplugindump tool has different levels of effectiveness.

Sorry to be so general, but hopefully it points you in the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

**From within QtCreator, do a "project-clean", and then rebuild.  The module will be found.**

I had the same problem and stumbled onto your question.  After some effort, the "clean" and rebuild worked.

There seems to be an "incomplete-dependency-checking" during the build process to "understand" that the `main.cpp` needed to be rebuilt, which would then expose the `qmlRegisterType<MyType>()` so that it can be found within the `main.qml`.

Answer (score 1):

After two days of googling and headache, thanks to @MoreMag, I finally worked it out! I just write down some key points here, hoping to help you guys!

### Problem:

[image: problem-found not working imports file]

### Solution:

① go to **Tools** ->  **Options** -> **Qt Quick** -> **QML Emulation Layer**.

② check **Use QML emulation layer that is built with the selected Qt**

③ click **Browse** button choose the Qt building environment bin folder. The path is in the form of *D:\Qt\5.15.2\msvc2019_64\bin*. Here I'm using the msvc2019 64bit building environment.

④ click **Apply** button and restart the Qt creater. **Done!**

[image: solution]

[Qt Creator document says](https://doc.qt.io/qtcreator/creator-qml-modules-with-plugins.html)

> A QML emulation layer (also called QML Puppet) is used in the Design mode to render and preview images and to collect data. To be able to render custom types correctly from QML modules, the emulation layer must be built with the same Qt version as the QML modules.
> By default, a fallback emulation layer is provided by Qt Creator and built with the same Qt version as Qt Creator. Therefore, your QML modules will mostly not work out of the box.

I guess this issue is caused by the fact that the default QML Emulation layer may not be compatible with some QML modules. In my case, it's QtMultimedia module.